# AppleScript: Difficulty replacing search HTML with search InnerHTML

Tags: javascript, applescript

I am new to AppleScript and would really appreciate it if anyone with experience could help me solve my problem. Below is basically what I want the script to do. This script I attached works, however I am not getting the search results from the text I am searching for. I read somewhere that I would need to to search InnerHTML with added javascript which I have no Idea how to do.

This is what I would like the script to do:

Open webpages one at a time from list in txt file

when webpage is loaded, then search for "text"

if "text" is not found

then

close tab, open next URL in list

if "text" is found

then

copy URL to a text file

once url is copied and saved

then

close tab, open next url in list

repeat

If anyone has the time to help me with this or point me in the right direction, I would be beyond grateful.
Thank you so much for your time.

```
on run {input, parameters}
read (item 1 of input)
set ps to paragraphs of the result
set tot to count ps
tell application "Safari"
    reopen
    activate
end tell
repeat with i from 1 to tot
    set p to item i of ps
    if p is not "" then
        try
            tell application "Safari"
                tell front window
                    set r to make new tab with properties {URL:p}
                    set current tab to r
                    delay 1
                    if i = tot then exit repeat
                    repeat
                        delay 1
                        
                        tell application "Safari"
                            activate
                            
                            --the source code of current Tab
                            set sourceOfTab to source of front document
                            
                            set urlOfTab to URL of front document
                            
                            if sourceOfTab contains "search term" then
                                
                                --copy of the url in textFile
                                do shell script "echo " & urlOfTab & " >> ~/Desktop/test.txt"
                            else
                                close current tab of front window
                            end if
                        end tell
                        
                        
                        
                        
                        
                        get URL of r
                    end repeat
                end tell
            end tell
        end try
    end if
end repeat
```

end run

Comment: Thank you for the response, however I do need to run the search using inner html.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello. I would like the script to use Safari to open a large list of URLs one by one from a text file on my desktop and search for a search item in the inner html of the site. If it finds the search item I would like the URL to be recorded in a separate text file. I would like Safari to open a new tab and close the tab automatically while the above function runs. The script I shared is accessing the text file through "Get Specified Finder Items" with thie shared Applescript below it. With this script I have to manually close the tab before a new one opens and find the search item myself.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think the problem is with your search routine. If I cut down the script to just the search routine, it appears to work:

```
tell application "Safari"
    --the source code of current Tab
    set sourceOfTab to source of front document
    set urlOfTab to URL of front document
    
    if sourceOfTab contains "search term" then
        --copy of the url in textFile
        do shell script "echo " & urlOfTab & " >> ~/Desktop/test.txt"
    else
        display dialog "Search term not found"
        --close current tab of front window
    end if
end tell
```

That is, if I have this question open, then the file gets created on the Desktop, because the text “search term” does appear on this page. If I change the search term to something that does *not* appear on this page, I get “Search term not found”.

To track down the problem, you’ll probably want to break the script into steps, and see which step is not doing what you wish. For example,

1. Make a version of the script that just steps through the URLs and displays them to you, so that you know that it is using the correct URLs.
2. Make a version of the script that steps through the URLs and opens them in a browser window, but does nothing else, so that you know that Safari is opening the correct web pages.
3. Only once the first two steps are doing what they should be would you add the search routine back in.

You may also wish to provide sample data within your script, so that we can run our experiments on the same data that you’re having trouble with. Currently, I’m not sure how you’re getting the data to the `run` handler, for example.

Here’s one example of doing this as a drag-and-drop application, that is, an application that accepts files dropped on top of its icon in the Finder (the files should be text files, one URL per line):

```
property searchTerm : "search term"
property matchFilePath : (path to desktop folder as text) & "Matching URLs.txt"

on open droppedFiles
    get path to desktop folder as text
    set matchFile to open for access file matchFilePath with write permission
    repeat with droppedFile in droppedFiles
        read droppedFile
        repeat with webURL in paragraphs of the result
            --ignore empty lines, which contain one character (the return)
            if the (count of webURL) is greater than 1 then
                tell application "Safari"
                    open location webURL
                    delay 1
                    set theRealURL to the URL of the front document
                    if the source of the front document contains searchTerm then
                        write theRealURL & return to matchFile starting at eof
                    end if
                    close current tab of front window
                end tell
            end if
        end repeat
    end repeat
    close access matchFile
end open
```

To test your script and provide advice, we’ll need to know how the URLs are getting to your `run` handler, and what format those URLs take. Also, while I think we have a pretty good idea of what you’re expecting a successful run to look like, you may also wish to describe more clearly the results that you’re seeing that you don’t want to see.